# Javascript Scope

Tags: javascript, scope

This is pretty self explanatory, I don't know why I'm getting the error since `process()` should be executing, but it's not.

```
function process () {
  var List = new Array("a","b","c");
}

function print () {
  if (typeof List == undefined) {
    process();
  }
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for (var i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
    var c = i+1
    doc.getRange("A"+c.toString()).setValue(List[i]);
  }
}

print();
```

ERROR: Line 10, List is not defined

Comment: Because `List` is defined **inside** a function. A fast and easy solution would be to globalize `List`

Comment: remove the var from process method.

Comment: @BenFortune: No, not really. Rather [difference between using var or not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/1048572)

Comment: Thanks, globalizing list worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can move the List var to outside of the function.

```
 var List =  [];
function process () {
 List = new Array("a","b","c");
}

function print () {
  if (typeof List == undefined) {
    process();
  }
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for (var i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
    var c = i+1
    doc.getRange("A"+c.toString()).setValue(List[i]);
  }
}

print();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are defining the variable `List` as a local variable, thus it will only exist in `process()`, define it as a global variable removing the private word `var`, here it is:

```
function process () {
    List = new Array("a","b","c");
}
```

Comment: Better, make it `return` the value. And you're not defining any variable there, you just assign to it - always *declare* it explicitly even if global.